# Post via Facebook android API indicates success, but cannot find it on Facebook site

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

One of the user's of my app, which allows for posting messages to their facebook wall, says that even though it is indicating success, he cannot find the message anywhere.

I've asked him to make sure the app is on his list of approved apps...and it is.

I've asked him to check his personal wall, since it seems you often do not see the app posting on your news feed, but you should always be able to see it on your wall.  He says it is not there either.

I retrieved the response from the request(), and it is of the form "id":"22346356_456354....".  I assume that's some kind of transaction ID, and is supposed to indicate success??  (I have no idea, because I CANNOT find anywhere a list of what the API responses might be).

Is that the code for "success", and if so, is there some way I can track down with that code just where his post actually went?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you got back is indeed a success response, and it is the id of the new post (as mentioned in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#statuses)), which is made of the USER-ID_POST-ID.

As for how to view that post, just direct your browser to:
`http://www.facebook.com/USER-ID/posts/POST-ID`

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  The post is there allright.  So if he can't view it in his timeline or other, then it has to be a facebook issue.